# JAVA, @Pattern(regexp="[[:Alpha:]]+") Only allowes aaaa's instead of alphabetic chars?

Tags: java, regex

```
@NotNull
@Pattern(regexp="[[:Alpha:]]+", message="Only Alphabetic chars allowed")
protected String name;
```

This only allowes aaaa's as input, e.g. trying to set the string to "apple" dosent work. But setting the string to "aaaaaa" work. I only want to allow alphabetic chars.

Comment: Java doesn't support POSIX character classes `[[:alpha:]]+` (with a lowercase `a`!). Therefore, it interprets your character class literally. Try `appl:` - that should "work" with your regex :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
@Pattern(regexp="\\p{Alpha}+", message="Only Alphabetic chars allowed")
```